# How do i include an echo statement inside another Echo statement in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, echo, src

```
<img src="{{ asset('public/image/{{$blog->image}}') }}" alt="post image">
```

this gives a parse error
PHP 8.1.2 9.3.1 Unclosed '(' does not match '}'
please how can i nest that {{$blog->image}} inside the image src without getting an error,
thanks

Comment: Try This `<img src="{{ asset('public/image/'.$blog->image) }}" alt="post image">`

Comment: Hey did my answer work for you? If so do not forget to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate strings with `.` just like in PHP.

When you use `{{ }}` inside a Blade template, it is like using `echo` in PHP. Just concatenate them with a `.` (dot).

```
<img src="{{ asset('public/image/' . $blog->image) }}" alt="post image">
```

Answer (score 1):

{{ }} behaves as an echo statement so you can't add echo in another echo. You just have to concatenate the string with variable like:

```
<img src="{{ asset('public/image/' . $blog->image) }}" alt="post image">
```